# ASP:Login Control - Changing authentication method

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I'm recreating a clients site moving them from one CMS to the another, however I've encountered a problem. The old site uses a salted MD5 encryption method and the new site uses an ASP:login control.

I want the login to first try and log in using the asp:lpgin controls method, and if the password seems incorrect, try the old sites way and update the password accordingly (seen as I can't get passwords out because they're encrypted).

Can anyone help me out an where to find/edit the asp:login controls authentication procedure?

Thanks in advance

Grant Unwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asp:Login` does not mandate any particular encryption/hash scheme.  If you're using it with the ASP.NET security provider it works according to whatever is configured in the web.config file.  However, you can subscribe to the control events, handle authentication yourself (using whatever custom scheme) and indicate success or failure.  See [Login.Authenticate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, I just found the OnAuthenticate event. Thank!